# Quick way to output a picture in C++

Tags: c++, image

I'm coding a physical simulation on 2d array and I'm now thinking that I could benefit from having a graphical output. My system is an array of cells (up to 2048*2048 of them) taking binary values, until now I used a prompt or text file output of '+' and '-' but it's not efficient for 2048*2048 lattice and maybe outputting in an image would be quicker and neater. Still, I've never done that. Ideally a library allowing me to write blue and red pixels/cell while parsing my lattice would get the job done. Are there some pre-existing not too long tools for doing it in c++?

Edit: I think that I just found what I was looking for: [png++](http://www.nongnu.org/pngpp/)

After no more than 10 lines of coding I got the following output:
[image: Yes I went to green instead of blue at the end...]

All I was asking for! Thank you for the suggestions ;)

Comment: You could post your last edit as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily get away without using an external imaging library by outputting a very simple format such as PGM or PBM. Refer to the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format) on Netbpm for more details, but you're essentially outputting all the values as either ASCII or binary numbers, then any image viewer or editor that supports PGM (many of which do) can open and display them. Even if you don't have an editor, something like ImageMagick can easily convert it to a PNG or any other more accessible format.

I've used this technique in the past to quickly visualize 2D data, as you're intending to.

Comment: Yikes, I was just about to post the same thing.  If you've already got it printf'ing out a grid of your data, it should be incredibly simple to hack it to output in one of these text based formats.

Answer (score 1):

C++ does not have native support for graphics. You need an additional C++ library.

Personally, I suggest you to use [Qt](http://qt-project.org/), which is free, powerful and cross-platform.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting Qt with which I'm a bit familiar as I already had to use it for another project but it seems overpowerful for what I'm trying to do, I'd just want some library allowing me to write an image pixel by pixel or with square cells of a few pixels to output a .png,.jpg or .bmp file ; nothing fancier. It shouldn't be necessary to pass by Qt for doing so.